# CreateOrUpdateView for Django Models

Tags: django, django-views

In my models I have a ForeignKey relationship like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):    
    question = models.TextField(null=False)

class Answer(models.Model):                                                    
    question =    models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answer')    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("question", "user"),)
```

the corresponding URL to submit an answer contains the id of the question, like this:

```
url(r'^a/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', AnswerQuestion.as_view(), name='answer-question'),
```

With user coming from self.request.user, I am trying to get something like a `CreateOrUpdateView`, to allow some convenient navigation for the user and URL scheme.

Until now I tried this with:

```
class AnswerQuestion(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
```

and add initial value, but that isn't clean because of pk. With an `UpdateView` I run into problems because I have to set default values for the form.

Has anybody done something like this? I'd rather avoid having a Create and Update view for the same Answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `UpdateView` and `CreateView` are really not that different, the only difference is that `UpdateView` sets `self.object` to `self.get_object()` and `CreateView` sets it to `None`.

The easiest way would be to subclass `UpdateView` and override `get_object()`:

```
AnswerQuestionView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    def get_object(queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()

        # easy way to get the right question from the url parameters:
        question = super(AnswerQuestionView, self).get_object(Question.objects.all())

        try:
            obj = queryset.get(user=self.request.user, question=question)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            obj = None
        return obj
```

Returns the right answer if it exists, `None` if it does not. Of course add any attributes you need to the class, like `model`, `form_class` etc.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Reading through documentation I got under the impression "get_object" is not relevant in case of "CreateView"s.

Comment: with the exception of:

    question = super(AnswerQuestionView, self).get_object(Question.objects.all())

which would not work, since I'm looking to create/update answer objects

Comment: That's why you're subclassing `UpdateView`, as that does use `get_object`. You need the question with the ID specified in the url to update the right answer or to create a new answer. The call to `super` with a queryset of questions is just a little trick to easily get the right question. The actual object returned by the `get_object` method that's called in the `get` and `post` method themselves is an answer or, if it doesn't exist, `None`.